# Using PMD in IntelliJ IDE with Illuminated cloud 2

Tags: pmd, illuminatedcloud

I am trying to use PMD in IntelliJ IDE using illuminated cloud. When I run PMD using pre-defined rules, no violations are reported. When I try to import custom rules from PMD's website, it does not load the custom rules and throws an error as shared in attachment.
[image]

Just to be clear, I am trying to run PMD for salesforce( apex) rules and want to see the bugs/errors from PMD in the IDE itself. I have searched all over the internet, did not find any support for it. Does PMD on intelliJ support apex ?
Has anyone here used PMD in IntelliJ IDE and able to see the static code review comments ?

Comment: Is that plugin perhaps using a very old version of PMD? The rules format underwent a significant change. (I don't use IntelliJ myself)

Comment: @Scott Wells would know =)

Comment: I am using the latest version from the plugin repository. The rules are also up to date.

Comment: That's not actually how you use PMD from within Illuminated Cloud. You can uninstall PMDPlugin from IntelliJ IDEA. Open Settings>Editor>Inspections, then select Salesforce>PMD Apex. You'll need to configure a PMD executable and PMD ruleset. The inspection configuration includes links to download the latest versions of both. Once installed, specify the paths to pmd.bat/run.sh and the ruleset XML file respectively. You can then run the inspection using Analyze>Run Inspection by Name. Let me know if that doesn't help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's my IC 2 setup.  The IDE has direct links to the files you need to have a path available from your local machine

[image]

Comment: Thanks @cropredy , Scott Wells. that helps in getting the issue resolved.  Appreciate your support.

Comment: @Dave - Scott gives terrific support on his [Illuminated Cloud Q&A support forum](http://www.illuminatedcloud.com/support) that I have used multiple times to post even 'newbie' questions and Scott answers promptly and cheerfully